# What data structure should I use for a list of keys and values in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, unity-game-engine

I have a config text file for a game in Unity that I will extract for a list of configurations containing a bunch of keys and associated values.

For example, the format of the text file goes like this:

```
ObjectColors Red Blue Green
ObjectShape Sphere Cube
ObjectSize Small Medium Large
...
```

The config file can be updated anytime with new keys, changes in order, new values and etc, hence the config file is pretty dynamic.

My question is, how should I organize and store these keys and values in C# so that I can retrieve them in an easy and efficient way. Right now, I'm planning on using dictionaries.

Comment: You should use List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>

Comment: [Key Value Pairs](http://www.dotnetperls.com/keyvaluepair)

Comment: @DinoMyte Are you trying to troll the OP?

Comment: @Servy: That was just an option. Feels generic list is the way to go :)

Comment: @DinoMyte So you want to replace a data structure that's literally designed to solve *exactly* this problem with one that's much slower, harder to use, won't provide the desired options out of the box, etc.?  What about it makes you think that it would be a good idea?

Comment: @Servy List<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>> has been used by me many times. If you dont need the key to be unique, and for instance you want to sort easly that List.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski If you had multiple values for each key (there is no such requirements) then you'd use a dictionary with the value being a collection/sequence of some type.  If you need the keys to be sorted, you'd use a `SortedDictionary`, because that's exactly what *it* is for.  The fact that you often use it doesn't change the fact that it's dramatically worse in many ways, and has no real advantages at all.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing them into a Dictionary is a solid choice. If you were to update an entry, it would just overwrite whatever was already there without you having to worry about old data. Plus the access time is quick.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But it'd probably be safer to just clear the dictionary and re-parse the config than just updating values. I'm assuming it's possible for someone to remove a key-value from the config which would then invalidate the potentially existing value in the dictionary.

Comment: Dictionary can have multiple similar keys.

Comment: I didn't think it can.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a small collection (10 pairs or less) of key/value pairs a ListDictionary, for larger sets of pairs or, if you don't know how many there will be a HybridDictionary is a good option.